# What type of ball bearing is this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, bearings

I don't have engineering background. I'm looking for this telescope' altitude bearing below. I understand it's a type of ball bearing, but does anyone know the exact name of this type?

There are 2 bearings, one on each side, allowing the telescope tube to move up-down

Increasing/decreasing friction is done by tightening/loosening the black knob, which looks like the size of a tennis ball, around 2"-3"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: bearings do not prevent overshoot when applied force is removed ... an opposing force has to be applied to counteract the inertia of the moving component

Comment: @jsotola This. You move the telescope properly by planning it's acceleration and deceleration such that you achieve a compromise balance between settling time (overshoot and undershoot) and reaching the setpoint in a minimum amount of time. It's called damping in control systems. Overdamped, underdaped, and critically damped. If you're controlling it by hand and not a computer, then that control system is you and I guess you need to develop the skill. This might be made easier by using a damping grease to make things require more force so it's not so jittery for your hands.

Comment: @DKNguyen that’s one reason why friction based dampers were invented prior to fancy control systems…

Comment: @DKNguyen so I guess I need to have damping grease added into these ball bearing. My main question is what do you call these ball bearing type? Do they have a name so I can Google Search them?

Comment: @Motoko Oh you're asking for the name of the type of bearing in your photo? Can you get an even bigger photo? The bearing on the left almost looks like a thrust bearing that uses rollers to me. But it's a bit weird that it's used vertically if that is the case. But if you are just looking for bearings that can support a much larger radial load than ball bearings, then you are looking for roller/needle bearings.

Comment: A nice way to make a controlled friction torque, is to press a metal washer into a plastic washer along the axis of rotation, and vary the axial force with an adjustment screw, spring, or both. Wonder if that might be what's going on, among the thrust bearing assembly. (??)

Comment: @PeteW Like a metal wave washer instead of a metal washer and a spring?

Comment: @DKNguyed, I had in mind more the metal-on-plastic contact (two flat washers), for a somewhat consistent coefficient of friction, and benign for wear at not-too-crazy cycle counts, like any manual adjustment mechanism would be. The spring element would be in addition to that and wave washer would definitely be a possibility.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh I see the confusion now, I have edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell there are two different types of bearing present.

The first one is this closed type. There is a marking which I believe is the *bearing number*.

[image]

I think I can make out a Z right at the end, which means that its a closed type. The rest of the number looks to me like 6005, which means that its a deep groove, single ball bearing with a bearing bore (hole diameter) of 25 mm.

---

Regarding the other one:

[image]

It looks like a thrust bearing (but I can't tell if it ball or something else).  If the black plastic thing underneath is threaded, and its used to tighten and untighten the assembly that would make some sense. (This is on the realm of educated guess. --- this would be easier if the whole assembly and the functionality and design intent was clearer).

Comment: The giant conical split / spring washer part is interesting. what material is it? might be what produces the axial force, doing the damping work???

Comment: That's my guess also. I can't really tell though.

Comment: Thanks so much @NMech! Some progress! Unfortunately I want to buy these for myself, and these pictures are from the internet. I have added some more pictures and updated the question to clarify.The way it works as I know is you tighten/loosen the black knob to increase/decrease friction, make it harder/easier to move move the tube up and down